# iTerm2: cd'ing into directory closes iTerm window

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2

I have a directory that I'm trying to `cd` into. It's a simple Rails app my friend built. The weird thing is, when I try to `cd` into it, the iTerm window closes. I've tried moving it from the directory it's in to the Desktop, but the same thing happens. I can run commands on the directory (like `ls`) from another directory, but `cd`'ing into the directory closes the window. I've never seen anything like it. How can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a shell issue. Dump the results of `set`.

Comment: It's quite a lot. Here it is on github as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/thenickcox/6026454)

Comment: Run `unset rvm_fail` and try entering the directory again.

Comment: Same thing. I also tried in normal Terminal with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's  answer, I thought this might have something to do with `rvm`. I don't know why this would fix it, but when I `cd`'ed into that directory using Terminal (instead of iTerm), before it hung, it told me that I didn't have the version of Ruby installed that was used by this app. So I ran `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p448`. This enabled me to successfully `cd` into that directory in both Terminal and iTerm2.

Comment: It's still in bad taste for it to kill the shell in use though.

Comment: Oh, definitely. That's why I'd love to know how this is happening.